# Рекурсия, многомерный массив, пропустить все ключи и их значения через

Tags: php, php8

```
function in($ms){
    foreach ($ms as $k => $v) 
        $nn[$k] = htmlspecialchars($v, ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");

    return $nn;
}
$nn = in([2,2]);

print_r($nn);
```

Передаю в функцию массив, через цикл проверяю каждое значение.

Вопрос в том, что если массив имеет следующий вид

```
[2,3,[5,2], ['test' =>'текст', ['m' => 42]]]
```

То есть не известно количество вложенных массивов, неизвестно что за ключ. Число или строка, так же не известен формат значения.

Как верно составить рекурсивную функцию, для того чтобы каждое значение и каждый ключ пропустить через 'strip_tags, htmlspecialchars, addslashes'. Для того, чтобы снизить уязвимость в данных местах.

Comment: "снизить уязвимость" --- Уязвимость от чего?

Comment: `array_walk_recursive`

Comment: Ок, рекурсивно перебираем массив. Вопрос в том, как на выходе получить тоже дерево. То есть как его так собрать?

Comment: кого собрать? `array_walk_recursive` структуру массива не меняет

Comment: Замечу, что  strip_tags, htmlspecialchars и addslashes нужны для совершенно разных ситуаций. Применять их просто на всякий случай глупо. Безопаснее не станет. Например ``javascript:alert(`XSS`)``, вставленный в атрибут href, может навредить пользователям, а `rm -rf` переданный в exec, запороть сайт.  Важно понимать что вы делаете и экранировать пользовательские данные исходя из контекста в котором вы их используете.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = [...]; // your assocc array
array_walk_recursive($data, static function (&$node) {
        if (is_string($node)) {
            // prepare and process your string values by htmlspecialchars, etc.
            //
            // example:
            $node = htmlspecialchars($node);
        }
});
```

[array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Comment: нормально так. был флоат, взяли в инт переделали.

Comment: @teran "и так сойдет"